# Using AND operation

Tags: java, xslt

guys the following is not working

```
<xsl:when test="caller:checkIfPresent(DOC) and $afflkExists='false'">
```

the function returns true and the variable is false, but it doesn't go inside the when clause. I tried putting braces like

```
<xsl:when test="(caller:checkIfPresent(DOC)) and $afflkExists='false'">
```

but when i make the value of the variable to true and change the above code to

```
    <xsl:when test="caller:checkIfPresent(DOC) and $afflkExists='true'">
```

It goes inside the when loop. What is the problem here? Am i missing something.

Comment: Could you provide input XML, and XSLT used?

Comment: Consider to post minimal but complete samples allowing us to reproduce the problem. Where do you declare the variable, which value do you assign (the boolean value `false()` or the string `false`)?

Comment: i just now modified the xslt to 
`<xsl:when test="(caller:checkIfPresent(DOC)) and $afflkExists=false()">
` and it worked.

Comment: am returning a boolean value

Comment: Am confused here. If am returning a true as a boolean the string comparison works for example i mentioned in the above example, but the same doesnt work for false. Why is it so?

Comment: See explanation in answer and http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#booleans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#booleans, if you have a comparison `expression1 = false()` where expression1 evaluates to a string value then any non-empty string is treated as the boolean value `true()` and that way the comparison is false for the string `'true'` as well as for the string `'false'` as both are non-emtpy strings.

Comment: Sir if my function is returning a boolean value `true` then why is expression = 'true' works and if boolean value 'false' is returned why expression = 'false' doesn't. Am no where returning strings. Am returning boolean values. Please clarify.

Comment: Second, if am returning boolean values from java functions then i should use false() and true() in xslt as `<xsl:when test="(caller:checkIfPresent(DOC)) and $afflkExists=false()">` or `<xsl:when test="(caller:checkIfPresent(DOC)) and $afflkExists=true()">` ?

Comment: I think I have explained how boolean comparison works and I have posted a link to the detailed specification. In XPath to write a boolean value there is no literal, you have to write the function calls `true()` respectively `false()`. If you know you have a boolean value (e.g. in a variable or as a result to a function call) then I would simply check `<xsl:when test="$myVariable">` to test for true and `<xsl:when test="not($myVariable)">` to test for false, I would not write `$myVariable = true()` or `$myVariable = false()`.

Comment: `I would not write $myVariable = true() or $myVariable = false()` 
any specific reason behind that?

Comment: Yes, in a language that has boolean values and boolean expressions the check `if ($var) ...` or `<xsl:when test="$var"> ...` suffices to test for true if $var has a boolean value and `if (not($var)) ...` respectively `<xsl:when test="not($var)"> ...` suffices to test for false, there is no need to compare a boolean value to a boolean constant. Only in a language without boolean values where some number or string has to be used to represent boolean values you need to write a comparison like `$var = 1` or "$var = 'true'" and make sure anyone uses the same representation in data and in code.